# What does "Y/Y" mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations

[In a power-point presentation about interent trends](http://www.kpcb.com/internet-trends), the abbreviation **Y/Y** is being used:

> 25MM+ people (+14x **Y/Y**) use Duolingo app to learn new language
>
> 12MM+ teachers / students / parents (+15x **Y/Y**) use Remind101 to send 500MM+ messages

Sadly, the video does not work, so I'm not sure what the abbreviation stands for. What does it mean in this context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer, Y/Y is likely to be an abbreviation of the phrase *[year-over-year](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/year-over-year#Adjective)*.  (Or sometimes *year-on-year*.)  Typically, a number before the phrase states a difference or ratio of one year's value of some statistic to the previous year's value.

For example, in [wikipedia's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_electric_vehicle) “Plug in electric vehicle” article, we find

> During the first seven months of 2014 the plug-in hybrid segment in the German market experienced a growth of 454% year-over-year.

This indicates that the 2014 value for plug-in hybrids registered during January through July is 1 + 4.54 or 5.54 times as much as the same statistic for 2013.  (The added 1 is due to 454% being the amount of growth, *ie* a difference rather than a ratio.)

In the examples given in the question,  “+14x” stands for “up by 14 times” and “+15x” stands for “up by 15 times”.  (It isn't clear to me whether they mean incremented by 14 times the previous value, or equal to 14 times the previous value.)

*Edit:*  As an abbreviation of year-over-year, *YOY* may be more common than *Y/Y*.  See [investopedia.com](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/y/year-over-year.asp) and [lexicon.ft.com](http://lexicon.ft.com/Term?term=year-on-year-YOY) for examples of use.

Answer (score 6):

It could be *[year-over-year](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/year-over-year)*, that is, "compared with the same period a year ago".

Comment: And what does that mean in combination with the `+14x` part before each **Y/Y**?

Comment: Frankly, it puzzled me too, @IQAndreas, that's why I used "could": I could be mistaken. There are 164 pages in the document, you'd better include the page number in your question.

Comment: It's from page 27, but the same abbreviation is used throughout the entire document.

Comment: +14x means an increase by 14 times the original quantity (read "increase by 14 times year over year"). So the first sentence implies that one year ago around 1.7 million were using the app, and this year 25 million are, which constitutes an increase of 23 million, around 14 times the base level of 1.7 million.